# DataReader running very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ssms

I'm currently working with a database of over 50 million records, where I  read a file which a person wants to search the database for etc. I have noticed my data reader part is running particularly slow, where as the query seems almost instant (database is indexed). I was just wondering does anyone know as to why it seems to be running slow?

con.Open()
        Using sw As New StreamWriter("G:\USER\SEARCH-RESULTS.txt")
            Try

```
            For Each word As String In result

                Using com As New SqlCommand("select t.SmeNbr, t.FilPth, r.MaxDate, t.DteAdd, t.LnePos from (Select SmeNbr, MAX(FilDte) as MaxDate from Test_Table where SmeNbr = @word group by SmeNbr)r inner join Test_Table t on  t.SmeNbr = r.SmeNbr and t.FilDte = R.MaxDate", con)
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word)
                    Using RDR = com.ExecuteReader

                        If RDR.HasRows Then
                            Do While RDR.Read
                                MyFilePath = RDR.Item("FilPth").ToString()
                                linePos = RDR.Item("LnePos").ToString()

                                Using sr As New StreamReader(MyFilePath)
                                    sr.BaseStream.Seek(4096 * (linePos - 1), SeekOrigin.Begin)
                                    FoundWords.Add(sr.ReadLine)
                                    For Each item As String In FoundWords
                                        sw.WriteLine(item)

                                    Next
                                    FoundWords.Clear()
                                End Using
                            Loop

                        Else

                            Continue For

                        End If
                    End Using



                End Using





            Next

    Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Couldn't process search")
    Finally
    con.Close()

    End Try
    End Using
    MsgBox("Complete!")
```

So it works perfect, as in it gets the records and bits of info I want very quickly through the query and all and even the writing reults to a new file is near instant, I used breakpoints and like I said it seems to take ages between the "Using RDR = com.ExecuteReader" and "If RDR.HasRows Then"

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the query seems almost instant" if you're indicating that the slowness is in executing the `ExecuteReader` line, since that's the line that runs the query.

Comment: So would execute reader also execute my whole "select t.SmeNbr, t.FilPth, r.MaxDate, t.DteAdd,"......etc.?

Comment: Yes, the methods named `ExecuteXxx` are the ones that execute the queries. Anything before that (except opening the connection) is just local preparation not involving the server at all.

Comment: Yes sorry I was being so stupid of course, then if you could help me understand as to why when I perform that query in MSSMS its near instant but it seems to take much long in VB to execute? Also is there a way to speed it up? Thank you btw! :)

Comment: What is the data type of the `SmeNbr` column? If it's `varchar`, the issue might be because `AddWithValue` infers `nvarchar` for the string value so indexes on the column might not be used. Create the parameter using one of the overloads that allow you to specify the proper type as described in [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: The data type of SmeNbr is Char(13). So should I change to something like
"com.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlDbType.Char, 13).Value(word)"

Comment: @K.Madden, yes. The reason it runs faster in SSMS is likely because you used a literal instead of parameter. You would have had the same issue in SSMS if you specified a Unicode string literal (e.g. N'SmeNbrValue').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", word)

`AddWithValue` infers the parameter data type from the provided .NET object value. Since .NET strings are Unicode, this code is will add an `nvarchar(n)` parameter with the length of the actual value. I see from your comments that the actual column data type is `char(13)` so it would be best to explicitly specify that as the parameter data type:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlDbType.Char, 13).Value = word
```

The implications with `AddWithValue` are that indexes might not be used due to the mismatched data type and there may be many variations of the same query in the SQL Server procedure cache that differ only by length. For these reasons, I suggest one [avoid AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm! Thank you so much. :D